# how to change conversation language of google assistant from webhook after the action is invoked

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, actionbuilder

I am working on a app in google assistant using the action builder. My default language is English. Now I want to add another language to my app. I did all the settings related to second language. It works if I call from the other one. Now I want to provide a facility to user to change language while running the action. How to do that?
Please help.

Comment: You can just ask for help directly. First, tell us how you are/will approaching the problem.

Comment: I have created the app in English. It is working perfectly. Now I want to extend it to Hindi. I did all the translations and did the invocation. it is also working nicely. now i want the facility that user can switch the language after the action is already invocaed. I checked "session.languagecode" but I didn't get what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The platform does not provide a mechanism to let you switch languages mid-conversation. If the user has both languages enabled on their Assistant, they will be able to initiate conversation in one of those languages.

The documentation provides more info on localization: https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/add-languages

Comment: Thank you for Guiding me. Is there any way to change language mid conversation from outside webhook or something?

Comment: No the platform doesn't let you change languages in the middle of a conversation at all.